# why do I get unexpected results when swapping two variables using pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

These are two functions I used for swapping variables using pointers while performing selection sort using the function `selectionSort(int *,int)`. But after sorting, some elements of the array become zero.

```
void selectionSort(int *x,int len){
    int i,j,max;
    for(i=len-1;i>=0;i--){
        max = 0;
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
            if(x[j]>x[max]){
                max = j;
            }
        }
        swap(x+max,x+i);
    }
}

void swap(int *a,int *b){
    //This one works perfectly
    int temp;
    temp=*b;
    *b=*a;
    *a=temp;
}


void swap(int *a,int *b){
    //This one gives unexpected results
    *a=*a+*b;
    *b=*a-*b;
    *a=*a-*b;
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the "unexpected results"? And please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us, together with the expected *and* actual results. Perhaps also take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: __1.__ your last edit is useless, it's just some numbers. We need a [MCVE]. __2.__ don't post pictures of text when you can post text.

Comment: Providing images to output is generally considered poor etiquette on SO. It is normally pretty easy to copy the output from your console and paste it into the question and add some formatting. Additionally, if you *do* need to add images for some reason, you should add them inline rather than just as a simple link

Comment: it was the output result that i'm getting

Comment: Sorry my mistake, i try to elaborate more by text

Comment: @VaibhavKumar yes, we know that it was the output of your program, but we need to see he program itself, not the output.

Comment: the swap functions are not the problem here. The numbers aren't big enough for the overflow. Selection sort must be the issue, but you're not showing it.

Comment: i've added the selection sort code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second swap algorithm does not work if both pointers point to the same variable which happens here if `max == i`:

```
swap(x+max,x+i);
```

Demonstration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
  //This one works perfectly
  int temp;
  temp = *b;
  *b = *a;
  *a = temp;
}

void swap_KO(int *a, int *b) {
  //This one gives unexpected results
  *a = *a + *b;
  *b = *a - *b;
  *a = *a - *b;
}

int main()
{
  int a = 22, b = 33;

  swap(&a, &b);
  assert(a == 33 && b == 22);   // OK

  swap_KO(&a, &b);
  assert(a == 22 && b == 33);   // OK

  swap(&a, &a);                 // OK
  assert(a == 22);

  swap_KO(&a, &a);              // won't work
  assert(a == 22);
}
```

Comment: can you please explain why the second algorithm does't work in that case?

Comment: now i got it, that is why the elements were becoming zero. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

Swapping two integers using arithmetic operators can result in integer overflow. Better to stick with the traditional approach.

BTW, you can use old school bitwise XOR operator for swapping (used to swap values in registers) but it would not give you any benefit over the method that uses a temporary variable. These days compiler are smart enough to optimize the code.

```
if (*a == *b) // If both integers are same then do not perform swap operation
    return;

*a ^= *b;
*b ^= *a;
*a ^= *b;
```

Comment: this one also gives the same unexpected result

Comment: @VaibhavKumar then we need a [MCVE]. Please.

Comment: I don't think XOR method is worth mentioning. It obfuscates the intent without providing any benefit. This answer would be better without it.

Comment: after sorting first few elements of the array becomes zero

Comment: @user694733; Agreed. Edited the answer.

Comment: The issue was actually not related to integer overflow, see my answer.

Comment: @MichaelWalz; Though issue is not related but solution is in the answer.